# What is a word for "loosely mirror" something/someone else?

Tags: single-word-requests

The student "loosely mirrored" the moves of the dance instructor, trying his best to mimic the motions.

Comment: What is wrong with "loosely mirrored"?  It seems to capture the correct sense better than any of the suggestions so far.

Answer (score 3):

To imply a less than perfect imitation, you might use 'aped':

*The student **aped** the moves of the dance instructor, trying his best to mimic the motions.*

> Dictionary.com:  verb (used with object), aped, aping.
>   5. to imitate; mimic: to ape another's style of writing.

Personally, I might consider that 'aped' and 'lumbered' (suggested by Phil) are both a little insulting to the subject, as they both suggest a lack of grace.

Answer (score 0):

Below are two candidates. The first one is a verb. The second is a noun.

[Miscopy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/miscopy?q=Miscopy):

> Copy (something) incorrectly.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

[Ersatz](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ersatz)

[Merriam-Webster]

> copied from something else and usually not as good as the original

Comment: @Rathony thanks. Always appreciated. I must have made mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Given the context, I would probably use a form of "followed", due to particular usage in dance contexts, and reference to movement/motion.

*The student **followed** the moves of the dance instructor, trying his best to mimic the motions.*

> 1. To come or go after, proceed behind.
>
> 3b. To go in the direction of; be guided by.
>
> 6. To take as a model or precedent; imitate.
>
> (American Heritage Dictionary, 2004)

Another option, though it doesn't seem to fit quite the same way, might be "copied" as in

*The student **copied** the moves of the dance instructor, trying his best to mimic the motions.*

> 2. To follow as a model or pattern.
>
> (American Heritage Dictionary, 2004)

Answer (score -1):

The student **lumbered** [through] the moves of the dance instructor, trying his best to mimic the motions.

> :  to move ponderously

"Lumber." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 28 Apr. 2016.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?

Answer (score -1):

*The student **monkeyed** the moves of the dance instructor*

> monkey
>
> : to imitate; ape; mimic.
>
> [Random House](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/monkey)

Comment: That is a rare definition of "monkey".  Most people would understand it to mean "manipulate".